# Should I use JavaScript prototypes in this situation?

Tags: javascript, templates, object, inheritance, prototype

I understand that in Javascript, prototypes may be used to provide a sort of implementation inheritance, and that that is useful to the Developer for defining objects which are refinements of more generic objects of a similar 'type' (e.g. Vehicle<-Car / Vehicle<-Bike)

But should I use prototypes for the following scenario...

1. An application provides the User the ability to create and edit "filters".
2. It's not really important what a "filter" is or does, other than having the following characteristics.

   a) Every filter is an object with exactly the same properties (and methods) as every other filter.

   b) A filter can be created by using another filter as a "template" (to which a reference is retained on the 'child' filter).

   c) A filter thus created may define none, some or all of its own values.

   d) Any values that aren't explicitly defined by the filter are taken from the filter's template.  Any not on the template come from the template's template, and so on up the chain.  If a value on an ancestor changes, all descendants which don't define their own value for that property will reflect the ancestor's changed value.  (<- This is why I'm thinking prototypes - they do this already!)
3. It is necessary to indicate to the User which properties are being inherited from a template filter, and which have been set on the filter itself.

So, is it good practice to leverage off Javascript's prototypes which already give me the functionality described in b) c) and d)?  Or should I define my own system of objects with pointers to other objects, and handle all the rules of inheritance myself somehow?

The reason I have a doubt is this...

Now imagine there are also different **types** of filter.  I can see that would easily be a case for using prototypes, where different types of filters *defined by the Developer* "inherit" from more generic prototypes, and contain additional properties & methods unique to the more specific type.  (E.g. Filter<-ColorFilter<-InvertColors)

Ok. So, if I were to use prototypes for the filter "templates" as well prototypes for the filter "types", then the inheritance chain would potentially be a big mixture of prototypes serving 2 different purposes i.e.

1) the *User-defined* filter-template inheritance chain, **and**

2) the *Developer-defined* filter-type inheritance chain.

Bad practice? Doesn't matter? Better solution? Question not clearly explained? 
Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve (and generally filters) is a good candidate to be implemented by [Composite Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

This can be easily implemented in JavaScript. Here are some articles with sample sources codes:

http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/composite-design-pattern
https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-design-patterns-composite/

Comment: Thanks!  I'll go check out the links before accepting an answer.

Comment: Just to clarify... are you suggesting the Composite pattern to handle the User-defined structure of filters and their templates, and use JS prototypes to implement the Developer-defined filter type object hierarchy?  Or vice versa, or use it for both?

Comment: Both should be possible.

Comment: Were you able to implement this?

Comment: I confess I never really understood how to use the "Composite Pattern" for this situation.  But, the way I ended up implementing this was to use the JS natural prototype inheritance chains to define BOTH: i) the "class" inheritance hierarchy for the different filter types (defined by me at design time) and ii) the hierarchy of filters using other filters of the same type as templates (defined by the user at run-time).

Comment: To help manage the filter hierarchy, I give each object convenience properties: i) "template" stores a reference to this filter's template, if any (It will just be the object's prototype, but only if the prototype is acting as a template with default values for instances of this type of filter, as distinct from prototypes acting as "parent class" definitions for different types of filter)   and... ii) "instances" stores a list of refrences to any filters which are using this object as their template.

Comment: When the user creates a new filter using an existing filter as a template, I call Object.create(), then update the relevant objects' "template" and "instancefs" properties manually (so I always know how many instances depend on each template, etc.) and to determine whether an instance defines its own value for a property or if it inherits the value from a template, I use obj.hasOwnProperty(). To help manage the "class" hierarchy, each filter has a property with the name of the type of filter it defines.

Comment: Was that anything remotely like the Composite solution? :-)  Shall I just go ahead and accept your answer?

Comment: What you said: "hierarchy of filters using other filters of the same type", looks like Composite pattern to me.

Comment: I'll take another, closer look at the Composite pattern now that I've implemented a solution,  it might become clearer to me, or possibly I've unwittingly implemented it without realising :-) Thanks again for your time, accepted this answer.